# Search Using Value Returned from Functions

Tags: solr, lucene

If I have something like this:

```
<doc>
  <field name="id">1</field>
  <field name="swaptot">4822536</field>
  <field name="swapavail">3743504</field>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="id">2</field>
  <field name="swaptot">15826924</field>
  <field name="swapavail">4881708</field>
</doc>
```

I am able to calculate the percent swap free.

```
q=*:*
fl=pctswapfree:ceil(product(div(sub(swaptot,swapavail),swaptot),100))
```

But how to I search for docs where pctswapfree:[50 TO *] only?

Is it possible to have a search query using a value returned from functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a filterquery with [`frange`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_3_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/FunctionRangeQParserPlugin.html) and your function query. `frange` will limit to a specific range.

`l` = lower bound
`u` = upper bound

```
fq={!frange l=50}ceil(product(div(sub(swaptot,swapavail),swaptot),100))
```

Query including an upper bound:

```
fq={!frange l=50 u=10000}ceil(product(div(sub(swaptot,swapavail),swaptot),100))
```